# os.walk exclude .svn folders

Tags: python

I got a script that I want to use to change a repeated string throughout a project folder structure. Once changed then I can check this into SVN. However when I run my script it goes into the .svn folders which I want it to ingore. How can I achieve this? Code below, thanks.

```
import os
import sys

replacement = "newString"
toReplace = "oldString"
rootdir = "pathToProject"


for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  print subFolders
  if not ".svn" in subFolders:
    for file in files:
      fileParts = file.split('.')
      if len(fileParts) > 1:
        if not fileParts[len(fileParts)-1] in ["dll", "suo"]:
          fpath = os.path.join(root, file)
          with open(fpath) as f:
            s = f.read()
          s = s.replace(toReplace, replacement)
          with open(fpath, "w") as f:
            f.write(s)

print "DONE"
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if '.svn' in subFolders:
      subFolders.remove('.svn')
```

And then continue processing.

Comment: Is there also an easy way of excluding all hidden files and sub-folders (starting with ".")?

Comment: I've found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454164/os-walk-without-hidden-folders

Answer (score 8):

[Err... what?](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes walk() again.

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  try:
    subFolders.remove('.svn')
  except ValueError:
    pass
  dosomestuff()
```

Comment: may i ask? i know that python follows the rule 'easier ask forgiveness than permisison' but in this case isn't better a simple if '.svn':#etc like in the example above? i find that syntax ugly; can you give me an advice?

Comment: @Ant: That's just how I roll.