# os.walk without hidden folders

Tags: python, linux, os.walk

I need to list all files with the containing directory path inside a folder. I tried to use `os.walk`, which obviously would be the perfect solution.

However, it also lists hidden folders and files. I'd like my application not to list any hidden folders or files. Is there any flag you can use to make it not yield any hidden files?

Cross-platform is not really important to me, it's ok if it only works for linux (.* pattern)

Comment: What platform are you on? 'hidden' has different meanings on different operating systems.

Comment: I'm on linux, I'll add that on the answer.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

No, there is no option to `os.walk()` that'll skip those. You'll need to do so yourself (which is easy enough):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d[0] == '.']
    # use files and dirs
```

Note the `dirs[:] =` slice assignment; `os.walk` recursively traverses the subdirectories listed in `dirs`. By replacing the *elements* of `dirs` with those that satisfy a criteria (e.g., directories whose names don't begin with `.`), `os.walk()` will not visit directories that fail to meet the criteria.

This only works if you keep the `topdown` keyword argument to `True`, from the [documentation of `os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know that you can modify the lists in place!

Comment: I ran this but it did not print anything to the console. What is the typical method to display the files found this way? I added `print root, dirs, files` at the end but it came out very messy.

Comment: @user5359531: that depends entirely on your usecase; you could `print '\n'.join([os.path.join(root, f) for f in dirs + files])`, etc.

Comment: Wander can `files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']` write like `files[:] = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']`, just like `dirs[:]` ?

Comment: @linrongbin: you could, but there would be no advantage in that. `files = [...]` binds `files` to a new list, and `files[:] = [...]` replaces the elements in the list `files` is already bound to. No other code is using that list when `os.walk()` gives it to you. `dirs` on the other hand is used by `os.walk()` to find the next directories to go and produce files for, so if you did *not* use `dirs[:] = [...]` then directories that start with a `.` are still going to be visited.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Cool, thanks, I'm not so familiar with python.

Comment: @linrongbin: also see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html to understand how Python variables work; it'll help to understand how the `os.walk()` implementation and the `dir[:] = [...]` interact.

Answer (score 14):

I realize it wasn't asked in the question, but I had a similar problem where I wanted to exclude both hidden files and files beginning with `__`, specifically `__pycache__` directories. I landed on this question because I was trying to figure out why my list comprehension was not doing what I expected. I was not modifying the list in place with `dirnames[:]`.

I created a list of prefixes I wanted to exclude and modified the dirnames in place like so:

```
    exclude_prefixes = ('__', '.')  # exclusion prefixes
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(node):
        # exclude all dirs starting with exclude_prefixes
        dirnames[:] = [dirname
                       for dirname in dirnames
                       if not dirname.startswith(exclude_prefixes)]
```

Comment: that is a great answer, works perfectly for excluding according to a list

Comment: FYI, `startswith` can also take a tuple of strings, so you can get rid of the inner for loop and just use `not dirname.startswith(exclude_prefixes)` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith (python 2.5 and up)

Answer (score 2):

My use-case was similar to that of OP, except I wanted to return a count of the total number of sub-directories inside a certain folder. In my case I wanted to omit any sub-directories named `.git` (as well as any folders that may be nested inside these `.git` folders).

In Python 3.6.7, I found that the accepted answer's approach didn't work -- it counted all `.git` folder and their sub-folders. Here's what did work for me:

```
num_local_subdir = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_folder_path):
    if '.git' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('.git')
    num_local_subdir += (len(dirs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that can allow you to skip those hidden folders using any and  map functions.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if any(map(lambda p: p[0] == '.', dirs)):
        continue
```