# in os.walk function hidden directories are missed

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to get the list of .ini files from a given directory.
it works fine except it is missing the hidden directory.

Below is the piece of code I am using, I need to include the hidden directory also when I am doing this.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):

    for name in files:

        if name.endswith(".ini"):    

            file_list.append(os.path.join (root,name))
```

Comment: are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454164/os-walk-without-hidden-folders. Seems that all directories are scanned.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) is documented to skip `.` and `..` and *symbolic links.* It shouldn't skip any other dirs. Can you provide some real code and a set of example problems that you're having?

Comment: thank you, the hidden dir what is missing is start with .registry, and it is configured as symbolic link, I think that is why it is skipped. Can you help what is the other function I can use to include them ?

Comment: Try `os.listdir` and possibly try glob.

Answer (score 0):

In macos, I had the same issue. I have no idea why some directories are being ignored arbitrarily in dirs.

As suggested in @Carl_M 's comment, I was able to get the full list of directories by using `os.listdir`:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    full_list_of_dirs = os.listdir(path)
```