# Hello, how does one ignore a directory like .snaptshot

Tags: python, os.walk

How does one ignore a directory like `.snapshot` or `.git` when using `os.walk` in Python?

Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
datasource = "/home/me/PYTHON/OGL_TOOLS"

def scanfolder():
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(datasource):
        depth = path.count('/') - 6
        maxdepth = 2

        if re.match ('^\S+.snapshot$', path) in dirs:
                print ('bad format')
                dirs.remove('.snapshot')

        elif depth <= maxdepth:
                for f in files:
                        #print (f)
                        if f.endswith('.txt'):
                                print (os.path.join(path, f))
                                filelog.write('\t{} =>  bonne syntaxe\n'.format(os.path.join(path, f)))


scanfolder()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.walk without hidden folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454164/os-walk-without-hidden-folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about checking for '.snapshot' or '.git' in a path and `continue` if found?

```
...
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(datasource):
    if '.snapshot' in path or '.git' in path:
        continue
...
```