# python walk directory tree with excluding certain directories

Tags: python

i am trying to walk a directory tree and exclude certain directories. Now, according to [os.walk exclude .svn folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276255/os-walk-exclude-svn-folders) for example i should be able to modify the 'dirs' list which would then let me prune the tree. I tried the following:

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/usr/lib"):
        print root
        dirs = []
```

I would have expected to not enter ANY subdirectories but i do:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/akonadi
/usr/lib/akonadi/contact
/usr/lib/akonadi/contact/editorpageplugins
/usr/lib/os-prober
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gtk-modules
/usr/lib/git-core
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools
/usr/lib/gold-ld
/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0
/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0/libexec
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of following

```
dirs[:] = []
```

OR

```
del dirs[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dirs = []
```

rebinds the local name `dirs`. You can modify the contents of the list instead eg. like this:

```
dirs[:] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

`root` gives the entire path and not just the root from where you started.

The docs makes it a bit more clear to what it's doing:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/usr/lib'):
    print dirpath
```

[See the docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)